# How to make a blank underline?

Tags: formatting

I'm looking to produce something like this:

blah blah ____ blah blah

But with a solid line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Phantom and line break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16003/5764); [Underlined blank that wraps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22181/5764); [How does one TeX a blank?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7473/5764); [“Fill in the missing words” needs line breaking before a \phantom{word}, and a list of removed words](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136774/5764)

Comment: Whoever voted to close this because it was already answered via [Phantom and line break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break) did not do their due diligence. (I hate it when questions get closed because of "possible" duplicates. If somebody's going to close a question, do it for the right reasons.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do it. Using `\rule[depth]{width}{height}`, I know you didn't provided a Minimal Working Example, but here it is a very simple example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    blah blah \rule{1cm}{0.15mm} blah blah
    \end{document}
```

The code produces the following output
[image: blank underline]

Comment: No need for the math mode (`$...$`)?

Comment: Confirmed - Works without math mode.